# Execute Javascript with WebBrowserWaiter

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I try to execute javascript using the WebBrowser surrounder [WebBrowserWaiter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebBrowserWaiter) like I do for a classic WebBrowser component :

```
         using (var wbw = new WebBrowserWaiter.WebBrowserWaiter())
        {
            wbw.Await(
                wb => wb.Navigate("URL"),
                wb =>
                {
                    HtmlElement hElement = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                    HtmlElement sElement = wb.Document.CreateElement("script");
                    sElement.SetAttribute("text", "function FuncName() {…}");
                    hElement.AppendChild(sElement);
                    wb.Document.InvokeScript("FuncName");
                },
                wb => strTxt = wb.DocumentText);
       }
```

But it seems that no HtmlElement is added to the WebBrowser when looking at the DocumentText property.

Has anyone ever tried to run javascript with WebBrowserWaiter?

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question asked in this GitHub issue, [WebBrowserWaiter | Issues | Cookies?](https://github.com/LeastOne/WebBrowserWaiter/issues/1#issuecomment-75697489) which demonstrates the following approach to JavaScript execution ...

```
waiter.Await(
    p => p.Navigate(url),
    p => {
        var head = p.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var script = p.Document.CreateElement("script");
        var element = script.DomElement as dynamic;
        element.text =
            @"(function() {{
                document.cookie = 'cookie=value; expires=Tue, 24 Feb 2016 03:59:53 GMT; path=/';
                document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
            }})();";
        head.AppendChild(script);
    }
);
```

There's also an additional example in the project unit tests [WebBrowserWaiterTests](https://github.com/LeastOne/WebBrowserWaiter/blob/master/WebBrowserWaiter.Tests/WebBrowserWaiterTests.cs).